# probablity distribution function

Tags: probability

A point is chosen uniformly from $(-10, 10)$. Let $X$ be the random variable defined so that $X$ denotes the coordinate of the point if the point is in $[ - 5, 5]$, $X = - 5$ if the point is in $(- 10, - 5)$, and $X = 5$ if the point is in $(5, 10)$. Find the distribution function of $X$.

I tried it to solve by integrating from $-5$ to $x$ but it is coming wrong answer $(x+5)/20$ while answer is $(x+10)/20$ in between $-5$ to $5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We find the cumulative distribution function $F(x)$ of $X$, that is, the probability that $X\le x$.

If $X\lt -5$, then $F(x)=0$.

If $x=-5$, then $F(x)=\frac{5}{20}$.

If $-5\lt x\lt 5$, then 
$$F(x)=\frac{5}{20}+\int_{-5}^x \frac{1}{20}\,dx.$$
This is $\frac{5}{20}+\frac{x-(-5)}{20}$, which simplifies to $\frac{x+10}{20}$.

Alternately, we can integrate $\frac{1}{20}$ from $-10$ to $x$. Or more simply, since the numbers came from a distribution uniform on $(-10,10)$, the probability is $\frac{x-(-10)}{20}$. The numerator is the length of the interval from $-10$ to $x$.

Finally, if $x\ge 5$ then $F(x)=1$.

Comment: Because if the original number is between $-10$ and $-5$, then $X=-5$. The probability that the original number is between $-10$ and $-5$ is $\frac{-5-(-10)}{20}$.  Or more simply, the probability that the original number is between $-10$ and $-5$ is $1/4$, since the interval from $-10$ to $-5$ represents $1/4$ of the original interval $(-10,10)$.

Comment: Note that the overall distribution of $X$ is neither continuous nor discrete. Because of the rule that any number between $-10$ and $-5$ is "recorded" as $-5$, there is a substantial positive probability that $X$ is *exactly* $-5$. That sort of thing cannot happen with a continuous distribution. Similarly, we get $\Pr(X=5)=1/4$.